# Strange SO rep behaviour documented

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Yesterday, I posted a question regarding strange behaviour on the SO Recent Activity - summary page. I deleted it because I thought maybe I really was imaginig it. Today I watched what was going on and wrote down the figures.

First of all, let me point out that this is taking place at 10.30 AM UK time, not on the hour as some suggested it should yesterday. The figures below are time and "Reputation earned" value:

```
10:25  236
10:28  406
10:29  236
10:30  0
```

So a couple of questions - why am I getting reset on the half hour, and what's with the 406 value? I've seen such bogus values persist for much longer periods than this before.

As I said yesterday, it's not that important, but at least I know now I'm not losing my marbles (yet)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's reasonably well-documented that if you click on the envelope to go to your summary page the stats about reputation gained, etc are not accurate for that day. If you click "today" they are.

I can't remember the specific reason for this but I believe that Jeff once commented it was performance related. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

It is confusing. Like early in the new day my figures will still include **some** of yesterday. I don't know what determines the start point for this but it would be nice if it defaulted to the day boundary for today.

Generally though the figure will stay consistent for a while (in terms of notional start point). I don't know what triggers it changing.

Are you seeing inconsistent results when you click "today" or just when you first go to the page?

Let me give you an example. Just now I clicked on the envelope and got:

[alt text http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/6624/recent1.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/6624/recent1.png)

If I click on "today" the display changes to:

[alt text http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/2599/recent2.png](http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/2599/recent2.png)

As you can see the first one doesn't show the reputation for today. What's stranger though is that it shows the comments for today but not the reputation. Clicking today gives the correct view.

Comment: Don't know - I generally just click the envelope icon. I'll try tomorrow using the tab (if I'm in).

Comment: I finally sat down and fiddled  with it a bit (like I said, it's not that important to me), and you are right, you get different results. Despite Jeff changing this from "bug" to "support" I think a bug - clicking on an alert (the envelope) should always give the current status.

Answer (score 1):

What time span are you looking at in the summary page? When you first click on the envelope it shows rep gained etc since midnight *server time* but if you click on "today" it will show you rep from the start of the UTC day.

FWIW, my tracker reckons that now (10:42 BST) you've earned 165, and yesterday you earned 243.

I have absolutely no idea why you'd see the values you've reported. For the 406, you definitely didn't click on "yesterday" did you? That means "yesterday + today" which would be 408 by my reckoning... close enough to be potentially significant?

Another factor *could* be vote fraud. I think when I "lost" a load of rep recently (due to someone mass upvoting me early in the morning) that happened around 10:30 UK time. Do you perhaps have a "fan" who is mass upvoting you? One easy way to guess that is to see if you get a lot of rep from different questions - on the day of the vote fraud for me, I'd received 200 rep by the time I got up, but from 19 different questions, which is very unusual.

Comment: No, in each case I clicked on the "envelope" icon. And this is not an isolated instance, so it can't really be put down to finger trouble. I don't think it's fraud, and it doesn't change my actual rep, as displayed at the top of each SO page. I suspect something a little funny in the SO code itself.

Comment: If it's just clicking the envelope icon, that's odd... I thought I'd seen that consistently return "server's idea of today".

Answer (score 0):

The server's timezone is utc+3 I guess. It's because you are in the UK.

Comment: The server's time zone is Pacific/Los_Angeles, I believe - currently UTC-7, and UTC-8 in winter time.